# update latest db row with postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to use postgres sql to update the latest row in the DB.

Here is how I get the latest row:

`SELECT id, state_json, update_timestamp FROM ui_rules ORDER BY update_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1`

How can I update and override that single row?

`UPDATE ui_rules SET state_json = '{..}' WHERE ?;`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `id` is unique, you can add a `where` condition or `join`:

```
UPDATE ui_rules
    SET state_json = '{..}'
    WHERE id = (SELECT id
                FROM ui_rules
                ORDER BY update_timestamp DESC
                LIMIT 1
               );
```